# SQL Server FREETEXT function with Specification and Criteria API in Spring

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-data, specifications, criteria-api

How do I correctly use the FREETEXT function from SQL Server in Spring using Specification and the Criteria API? I can't directly use native query because I have other conditions that are dynamically added to the query via Specification.
I have tried the following but without success. The resulting query doesn't contain the FREETEXT(statement_text,'Weaponization') and it just gives weird results:

```
    static Specification<HearingEntity> hasSearchTermEquals(String searchTerm) {
        return (root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Join<HearingEntity, HearingSpeakerEntity> hearingSpeaker = root.join(HearingEntity_.speakers);
            Join<HearingSpeakerEntity, SpeakerEntity> speaker = hearingSpeaker.join(HearingSpeakerEntity_.speaker);
            Join<HearingEntity, StatementEntity> statement = root.join(HearingEntity_.statements);

            criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.function("FREETEXT", Boolean.class, statement.get(StatementEntity_.statementText), criteriaBuilder.literal(searchTerm)));

            return criteriaBuilder.or(criteriaBuilder.like(root.get(HearingEntity_.hearingTitle), "%" + searchTerm + "%"),
                    criteriaBuilder.like(speaker.get(SpeakerEntity_.fullName), "%" + searchTerm + "%"));
        };
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried registerFunction("FREETEXT", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN, "FREETEXT(?1) AND 1"));

Comment: No, I haven't. Where do I use this? Do I have to create a new configuration component in order to register the function?